# Symmetrical points

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-transformation

$\triangle ABC$ is given, in which $AC > BC$ and the incircle $k(O)$ touches $BC$ and $AC$ in $M$ and $N$, respectively. Point $B_1$ is the image of B with respect to the line $CO$. Show that $M$ and $N$ are symmetric with a respect to $CO$ and $B_1M = BN$ and $AM > BN$.
[image]

As it is in the drawing, $B_1$ lies on $AC$, but I do not know how to show it. For the first part of the problem, I should show that $CO$ is the perpendicular bisector of $MN$. This is because $NC=MC$ (tangent segments) and $ON=OM=r$, thus points $C$ and $O$ determine the perpendicular bisector of $MN$. Let us denote $CO$ with $a$.

$\sigma_a:B \to B_1$

$\sigma_a:M \to N$ (here I am not sure if there's a difference with $N \to M$, and if there is I would be very grateful if someone could explain to me)

I don't know how to show the next things. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to denote the incenter by $I$, and leave $O$ for the circumcenter.  Anyway:

There is no difference using $\sigma_a\colon M\mapsto N$ or $N\mapsto M$, since $\sigma_a$ is an involution (i.e., do it twice will give you back the original point).  However, in the name of consistency, it is better to use $N\mapsto M$ since you used $B\mapsto B_1$ before, for the next line:

- $\sigma_a$ maps the segment $BN$ to the segment $B_1M$, hence $B_1M=BN$.

Finally, to show $AM>BN$, note that $CB_1B$ is isosceles, so $\angle AB_1B$ is obtuse.  Thus $\angle AB_1M$ is also obtuse, and $$AM^2>B_1M^2+AB_1^2>B_1M^2=BN^2.$$

Comment: Thank you for your response! I understood the first part, but I don't get why $\angle AB_1B$ is obtuse and the next equalities.

Comment: I see that $\triangle B_1BC$ is isosceles with $\angle BB_1C = \angle B_1BC$.

Comment: $\angle BB_1C<90^\circ$ because \begin{align*}180^\circ&=\angle BB_1C+\angle B_1BC+\angle BCB_1\\&=2\angle BB_1C+\angle BCB_1\end{align*}So its supplementary angle $\angle AB_1B$ is obtuse.

Comment: I got it. Was I right for saying that $B_1$ lies on $AC$?

Comment: yes, $B_1$ lies on $AC$, because the line $CM$ extended is reflected to $CN$ extended by $\sigma_a$.

Comment: So if a point lies on $CM$ it's sure that its image lies on $CN$?

Comment: The final inequality is one characterisation of triangles: the angle $C$ is acute, right, or obtuse iff $c^2-a^2-b^2$ is $<0$, $=0$ or $>0$ respectively.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! I only knew that in a right triangle $c^2 = a^2 + b^2$ or $c^2 - a^2 - b^2 = 0$.